# Loading Animations while app gather's data

Tags: android, asynchronous, loading, splash-screen

I'm working with an app that grabs a decent amount of data upon start each time since I need to immediately know things like location and weather fcst in the area.

In my mind I see a loading animation that smoothly moves around for 3 to 7 seconds while everything runs so there isn't just a blank screen or a static title image.

BUT:: I'm running into issues with getting animations or images to load before all of the data is searched for. And I only want the animation to run as long as data is loading. So I have the application switch to a new activity as soon as everything is loaded.

Is there a way to for the animation to run before things are done or do I need to somehow set everything up as an async task. And then how do I pass the async task to the next activity?

Comment: where is implemented code?

Comment: Please keep in mind to post your code which you have tried while asking questions. Otherwise it becomes hard for the community to help you and will just ignore or down vote it. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found an answer to my own question after reading some books. In short, the loading screen that i was looking for uses a splash screen with asynchronous tasks. Either AsyncTask directly or you can implement a service solution.

Extra: I noticed that if you run an async task which starts a GoogleAPIClient, onConnected executes on a pool thread or something, point being you can do UI work on the main thread again without wrapping back to AsyncTask.